The curves of the equation $\sqrt[y]{x} + \sqrt[x]{y} = n$ intersect at $n≈2.88933572$. Is there any significance to this number?
Please see this short, compact video for an understanding of what I mean.
I'm not asking about the weirdness of taking the y-th root of x and the x-th root of y, my question is solely about the number stated above . I tried searching its digits in the OEIS, but to no luck.
Is there a closed-form expression for this number?

The number seems to be $2e^{1/e}$, seeing that the curves appear to intersect at the point $(e,e)$.

@MartinArgerami You're right! Feel free to make that an official answer and I'll accept it.

I would wait. Maybe someone knows how to treat the problem analytically.

Could you tell me what is the plot of what vs what. I cannot see it (I am blind). Thanks

@ClaudeLeibovici It's really not a plot of a typical function as it violates the vertical line test. Instead the equation has two separate components when graphed: A hyperbola (well, hyperbola-like, I'm not too keen on definitions), and a closed curve to its left. As n increases, the two components get closer and closer to each other until they merge. The value for n where they merge is what we determined.

There is an entry in the OEIS for $e^{1/e}$ A073229 with some interesting facts.

As it was already mentioned in comments, this number is $2 e^{1/e}$.
Note that the plot of $x^{1/y} + y^{1/x} = N$ is symmetrical about the line $x = y$ for any $N > 0$. It follows from symmetry that the intersection point has $x = y$, and it can be seen from the plot that it's in fact a singular point on a curve (having no tangent line):

Let's start by finding $y'(x)$, treating $y$ as a function of $x$:
$$
x^{\frac{1}{y}} + y^{\frac{1}{x}} = N \Rightarrow \left(x^{\frac{1}{y}} + y^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)'_x = 0 \Leftrightarrow 
\left(e^{\frac{\ln x}{y}} + e^{\frac{\ln y}{x}}\right)'_x = 0 \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow 
e^{\frac{\ln x}{y}} \left(\frac{1}{x y} - \frac{\ln x\cdot y'}{y^2}\right) + 
e^{\frac{\ln y}{x}} \left(\frac{y'}{x y} - \frac{\ln y}{x^2}\right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow
x^{\frac{1}{y}+1} \left(y - x \ln x\cdot y'\right) + y^{\frac{1}{x}+1} \left(x y' - y \ln y\right) = 0 \Rightarrow
y' = \frac{y}{x} \cdot \frac{x^{\frac{1}{y}+1} - y^{\frac{1}{x}+1} \ln y}{x^{\frac{1}{y}+1} \ln x - y^{\frac{1}{x}+1}}.
$$
It can be seen that $y'$ is defined for all points on the curve except the ones with $x^{\frac{1}{y}+1} \ln x - y^{\frac{1}{x}+1} = 0$.
Hence, it leads to a system of equations for $x, y, N$ to find a value of $N$ for which there is a point on the curve with $x = y$ such that $y'$ is not defined here (and hence tangent line does not exist):
$$
\begin{cases}
x^{\frac{1}{y}} + y^{\frac{1}{x}} = N \\
x^{\frac{1}{y}+1} \ln x - y^{\frac{1}{x}+1} = 0 \\
x = y
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
2x^{\frac{1}{x}} = N \\
x^{\frac{1}{x}+1} \left(\ln x - 1\right) = 0 \\
x = y
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
2x^{\frac{1}{x}} = N \\
x \cdot \frac{N}{2} \cdot \left(\ln x - 1\right) = 0 \\
x = y
\end{cases}
$$
So, it means that $x = y = e$, and $N = 2 e^{1/e}$.

Very nice solution indeed !
